# extract only integer from txt

Tags: python, numpy

I have a txt file which contains lost of information,I do not want its head and tail, I need only numbers in the middle. which is a 1x11200 matrix.

```
[txtpda]
LT=5.6
DATE=21.06.2018
TIME=14:11
CNT=11200
RES=0.00854518
N=5
VB=350
VT=0.5
LS=0
MEASTIME=201806211412
PICKUP=BFW-2
LC=0.8
[PROFILE]
255
256
258
264
269
273
267
258
251
255
259
262
260
256
255
260
264
266
265
263
261
263
267
275
280
280
280
280
283
284
283
277
279
280
283
285
283
282
280
280
286
288
298
299
299
299
304
303
300
297
295
296
299
301
303
301
299
296
298
299
302
303
304
307
308
312
313
314
312
311
311
310
312
310
309
305
303
299
297
294
288
280
270
266
250
242
222
213
199
180
173
...
-1062
-1063
[VALUES]
Ra;2;3;2;0.769;0;0;-1;0;-1;0
Rz;2;2;2;5.137;0;0;-1;0;-1;0
Pt;0;0;0;26.25;0;0;-1;0;-1;0
Wt;0;0;0;24.3;0;0;-1;0;-1;0
```

now I using the following method to extract numbers:

```
def OpenFile(): 
    name=askopenfilename(parent=root)
    f=open(name,'r')
    originalyvec1=[]
    yvec1=[]
    if f==0:
        print("fail to open the file")
    else:
        print("file successfully opened")
        data=f.readlines()
        for i in range(0,14):
            del data[0]//delete its head（string)
        del data[11204]//delete its tail（string)
        del data[11203]//delete its tail（string)
        del data[11202]//delete its tail（string)
        del data[11201]//delete its tail（string)
        del data[11200]//delete its tail（string)
        for line in data:
            for nbr in line.split():  //delete \n
                yvec1.append(int(nbr))
    if f.close()==0:
        print("fail to close file")
    else:
        print("file closed")
```

I want to use numpy to manage it in a easy way. Is that possible?
like np.array or something like that.

Comment: So the data you would want to acquire is the data after the [PROFILE]  and before the [VALUES] string?

Comment: exactly!  that is what I want to do

Comment: well then Ill post an answer too. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a alternative form of `iter()`, where you pass `iter()` a function and it will keep calling that function until it sees the value (2nd arg). You can use this to skip until you see `[PROFILE]\n` and then use that same form of `iter()` to read until `[VALUES]\n`. The function is just the one called by `next(iterable)`, which is `iterable.__next__`, e.g.:

```
with open(name) as f:
    for _ in iter(f.__next__, '[PROFILE]\n'):   # Skip until PROFILE
        pass  
    yvec1 = [int(d) for d in iter(f.__next__, '[VALUES]\n')]
```

`yvec1` will now contain all values between `[PROFILE]` and `[VALUES]`.

An alternative and potentially quicker way to consume the first `iter()` is to use `collections.deque()` instead of the `for` loop but this is likely over-kill for this problem, e.g.:

```
deque(iter(f.__next__, '[PROFILE]\n'), maxlen=0)
```

Note: using `with` will automatically `close(f)` at the end of the block.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace everything from the line `data=f.readlines()` and below with:

```
data = [int(line) for line in map(str.strip, f.readlines()) if line.isdigit() or line.startswith('-') and line[1:].isdigit()]
```

And `data` will be the list of integers you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you the idea this may help
The s3[0] will be all the numbers between PROFILE ans VALUES

```
#s=your data
s='sjlkf slflsafj[PROFILEl9723,2974982,2987492,886[VALUES]skjlfsajlsjal'
s2=s.split('[PROFILE]')
s3=s2[1].split('[VALUES]')
```